# Samba doesn't seem to stay joined to Active Directory domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, winbind

I can initially join a linux box to the domain with these commands:

`sudo kinit administrator@WINDOWS.CORP.SPRINGVENTUREGROUP.COM
sudo net ads join -k`

After a few hours or the next day, this happens:

`user@host:~$ sudo wbinfo -a administrator
Enter administrator's password: 
plaintext password authentication failed
Could not authenticate user administrator with plaintext password
Enter administrator's password: 
challenge/response password authentication failed
error code was NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022)
error message was: Access denied
Could not authenticate user administrator with challenge/response`

These commands work as expected all the time:

`sudo wbinfo -t
sudo wbinfo -u
sudo wbinfo -g
sudo wbinfo -i administrator`

Samba Version 4.2.5-SerNet-Ubuntu-8.trusty, here is my smb.conf

`[global]
    workgroup=WINDOWS
    security=ads
    realm=WINDOWS.x.x.COM
    domain master=no
    local master=no
    preferred master=no
    load printers=no
    printing=bsd
    printcap name=/dev/null
    disable spoolss=yes
    idmap backend=tdb
    idmap uid=10000-99999
    idmap gid=10000-99999
    idmap config WINDOWS:backend=rid
    idmap config WINDOWS:range=10000-9999
    winbind enum users=yes
    winbind enum groups=yes
    winbind use default domain=yes 
    winbind nested groups=yes
    winbind refresh tickets=yes
    winbind offline logon=yes
    template shell=/bin/false
    client use spnego=yes
    client ntlmv2 auth=yes
    encrypt passwords=yes
    restrict anonymous=2
    log file=/var/log/samba/samba.log
    log level=2
    dcerpc endpoint servers=remote`

Nothing useful in the logs :(

`[2015/11/25 15:26:23.524927,  2] ../source3/libsmb/cliconnect.c:1306(cli_session_setup_kerberos_send)
  Doing kerberos session setup
[2015/11/25 15:26:23.532756,  2] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_pam.c:2016(winbind_dual_SamLogon)
  NTLM CRAP authentication for user [WINDOWS]\[administrator] returned NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

Any help appreciated

Comment: My question meets every single one of those criteria.... Why did you mark this as on hold?